# Code in c# for determining whether Oracle DB is listening to port 1521 on a specified remote machine

Tags: c#, oracle, sockets, networking, port

I would like to know whether oracle DB is listening to port 1521 (or maybe another specified port) on a specified remote machine using c# code. Tools like nmap are able to do it - unfortunately I cannot use nmap / such tools and have to build in the code.

I tried using the Process.GetProcesses() method - but it does not give the port no. So that did not work for me.

Highly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Why do you want to do this? Is it to determine that the requested database is available? Then just connect to it using DB code, because a process listening to a certain point is no guarantee that your application will work. There can be another application listening on that port (not speaking the Oracle wire protocol), or there can be errors in your connection string (wrong database, wrong credentials). Your port check will then give a false positive, while your code will still fail. The question _"How to check a port"_ has been answered plenty of times before.

Comment: I need this to scan which servers on my network are running Oracle DB (as an example).   I am able to determine whether port is listening or not - thanks to many contributions  on stackoverflow. Unfortunately, none have gone into the area of identifying the service on the port. The Process.GetProcesses() method gives all details but the port no. So approaching from that side of the process did not work for me. I tried to use the socket.beginconnect() method - which help me understand which port is listening - but doesn't tell me who is listening on the port. I am not able to bridge these two

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is using TNS ping:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { CreateNoWindow = true, UseShellExecute = false, FileName = "tnsping", Arguments = "localhost:1521" };
var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
```

And then check the `process.ExitCode`. If the value is 0 then the ping was successful otherwise it failed.

With TNS ping you can use both TNS names or EZ-Connect connection types.

Comment: This works only when you have tnsping.exe installed - that isn't always the case.

Comment: Thanks. As Wernfried commented ... it needs tnsping installed. Moreover, I don't know whether port 1521 is being used by oracle or the user might have used a different port. I need a simple method to know which ports are listening (which I am able to do ) and then to know who (which program/services) are listening on those ports - which I am not able to and need help!